# Implementing inheritance in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python-2.7, inheritance

I have to create two class objects with large number of variables `A` and `A_son`. Class object `A` is subset of `A_son`. So, I decided about inheriting `A` into `A_son` and adding 2 more variables to `A_son` as follows:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, a1, b1):
        self.a1 = a1
        self.b1 = b1

class A_son(A):
    def __init__(self, a2, b2):
        super(A_son, self).__init__()
        self.a2 = a2
        self.b2 = b2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A(1, 2)
    a_son = A_son(a, 4, 5)
```

I am trying to achieve the following result:

```
print a_son.a1 #expecting 1
print a_son.b1 #expecting 2
print a_son.a2 #expecting 4
print a_son.b2 #expecting 5
```

Obviously I am not able to implement this correctly.

Edit:
Can you please show me correct syntax implementation?

Comment: `super().__init__()` just calls the `A.__init__` method. That method still expects to get 2 arguments, you didn't supply those.

Comment: If you want `A_son()` to accept an instance of `A` as a source for the attributes, you still have to pass those on explicitly. They is no implicit 'copy from this instance' operation here.